# Swift autogenerated header missing new swift classes

Tags: objective-c, swift, header, code-completion

I am working in this project where I have a mix of old pre-ARC et ARC Objective-c files co-existing with swift since the start of the year. For some reason, that I can not find, to day all new Swift files I have added set to public are not being added to the Swift auto-generated header. 
I have check target ownerships, build phase, that it is public as @objc and inherits NSObject. still I can not call the class from Objc and I can from other swift class. it is as if it was set to be private to the swift module or something even after setting it access  public..

for example :

```
@objc public class SomeSwiftClass: NSObject
{
    public func sayit()
    {
        print("Hello!")
    }
}
```

this does not show in any of the OBjc classes where project-swift.h is imported. I am able to call previously created classes, but not the one I added today.

I would guess that some setting is wrong if all my classes are no longer available, but no just the new class !!?!??!?!?!?!?!?!?!

Edit:
- restarting Xcode does not fix it. 
- rebooting system does not fix it. 
- deleting derived data does not fix it.

strange thing building while having 1 line of code in Objc accessing the swift class does not cause an error. So Its looking like some type of problem with code completion.

Comment: Are you quite sure the project is compiling and linking happily? It'd be the absolutely simplest explanation… :)

Comment: Just a few warnings that dont relate tot the file and no errors. Cleaned the project and quit xcode, no changes. I will reboot my system see if this fixes the problem;

Comment: A reboot later. no change, getting the same problem using the beta.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I've run into it a few times as well and have yet to understand the cause. Was this code working at a particular point in time or is it just the new code that's not appearing? What does the swift header file look like in your derived data folder?

Comment: If I build or run it, yea its all good. and with time the new class or entity end up getting picked up by the syntax preprocessor. My guess its a bug from xcode. its a odd behaviour, but the class that made me post this is not coming up when I type it and no longer put an error in the editor before I build. So at some points it just wakes up. its like I have a few versions of the <projectName>-Swift.h file and the one used by the syntax checker is out of date eve after a build.